# WildFly 8.2.0 - Lost connection to the server

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

I try the new version of WildFly: 8.2.0 (I was with the 8.1.0) on Windows 8.1 with JDK 1.8u25

So I install wildfly, add user, add WildFly to NetBeans, go to the admin console (on Firefox 34), add jdbc driver in runtime and then click on Configuration to setup the datasource but there is a popup saying "Lost connection to the server", I restart but the problem remain, I reinstall and the problem remain

Each time I click on configuration I have the popup : "Lost connection to the server"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reloading the admin page (using F5 or Ctrl+R) also worked for me. I think the browser cached the old console.

Comment: You need to manually clear the cache.  Refreshing does not do this by default.

Comment: @jordanpg, you should add this as an answer.

Comment: Really strange this occurs, JBoss EAP 7.0 has never done it.  The F5 worked for me as well - thanks